# Complement Theorem and Steinitz Theorem, are the same thing?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

There is a theorem about basis of a vector space that says:

> Let $u_{1}, u_{2},...,u_{p}$ be linear independent vectors of some vector space, $E$. Suppose that each $u_{i}$, with $i=\{1,2,3,...p\}$ are linear combination of some vectors $v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{k} \in E$. Then it's possible to replace $p$ of the $v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{k}$ by $u_{1}, u_{2},...,u_{p}$ and get a equivalent system to $v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{k}$.

The book from where I read call this statement Steinitz Theorem. Does this statement has another name, like Complement Theorem? Thanks.

Comment: When I studied this, they called it the "replacement theorem".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steinitz theorem is called [*Steinitz exchange lemma*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma) at Wikipedia (translation from the german "Steinitz Austauschsatz"). It says that if given a set $\{u_1,\ldots ,u_p\}$ of linear independent vectors in $V$, and $w_1,\ldots ,w_n$ span $V$, then $p\le n$, and the set
$\{u_1,\ldots ,u_p, w_{p+1},\ldots ,w_n \}$ spans $V$ (possibly after reordering). The words "exchange" and "replacement" are quite related, but also "complement" theorem is quite close by.